# VOTE - The site needs it

Tags: discussion, site-health, voting

If you look at our [stats](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82707/elementary-os) on Area 51, you will see that one of the areas where we are falling behind is in the number of users with a good reputation. This is sad, because we do have quite a good answer rate, and so we most likely have a large number of [users](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) who are not getting the upvotes they deserve.

Of course, this could also mean a smaller number of users are doing all the heavy lifting. Either way, for the site to remain healthy, you need to vote (up or down) on questions and answers where you can. Just remember - vote fair and honestly, because the system *is built to catch fraud*, and the moderators are also watching (even when we are sleeping, with one eye open!) ;)

If you are new to Stack Exchange, as likely many of our users will be, here's some further reading:

- https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote
- https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Don't pay much attention to Area 51 stats, they were chosen in 2010 and somehow never removed even though experience shows they aren't very useful. In any case, this stat is a cumulative one, of course the number of high-reputation users is be low when the site is young!

Comment: You can see comparative voting statistics at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/195762/average-number-of-votes-on-all-sites . But there's a lot more activity (including voting) during the first few weeks, so it'll be months before the figure for elementary OS can be meaningfully compared with other sites.

Comment: Just that you know I do my part: I have reached my voting limit today ;)... But the only stat I would really care about is answer rate (hoping they are high quality answers), everything else will be reached easily over time.

Comment: *36 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers...*  It probably wouldn't hurt if mods started closing questions without activity. There are plenty where OP's haven't bothered responding to questions for more information etc.

Comment: @elmato flagging helps in that regard - a lot :)

Comment: Fair call. I'll have a skim through and flag a few. How long do you think is reasonable before a question should be marked as inactive?

Comment: @elmato on AU we usually go with 3 months, but I'd prefer to open a new meta question here to let the community decide.