# Things to work on for the betterment of elementary OS SE

Tags: discussion

elementary OS Stack Exchange site have been in beta for around 1400 days. If we look at the facts and figures at the [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82707/elementary-os) you will see that we need to work on **answered question percentage** and we need to **promote this site**.

[image]

Our site's **visit/day** stat is okay, **users** is also okay. I think **answer ratio** will improve by more interacting with questions. Which I believe will eventually improve if we can improve **questions per day**, why? Well I think if there's more people asking question meaning there's more users and more users means increase in the amount to total active users. Also, we can just post **valuable-helpful information** if not posted already to increase the rate.

We need to promote the site not only people using elementary OS turns to us but also more people show interest in elementary OS itself.

And those of who are actively monitoring the site I think I found [a job for you](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109/vote-the-site-needs-it)! As I was saying we need to work on **answered question percentage** - there's a lot of answers worthy of up votes but have none. Voting to those answers will not only increase the percentage but also will inspire the answer authors to **interact more**.

[People have tried before](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214/do-not-take-no-for-an-unanswer) but sadly, some of them lost enthusiasm or been very busy with their lives. So, let's [vote](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ano%20migrated%3Ano%20wiki%3Ano%20isanswered%3A0%20closed%3A0%20hasaccepted%3A0%20answers%3A1) and promote site. But do vote when a question and answer deserve only.

Please visit [Help Center](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how to use the site and check [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites?rq=1).

[Here's a list of around 600 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/elementaryos/query/1036019/asked-but-answers-having-less-score) that don't seem to have any upvote  on posted answers. Let's try to lessen it.

Have a nice day.

Comment: And please let me know what you think. I would like to here from everyone.