# Should We Ask Questions We Can Answer to Build Content?

Tags: discussion

Two years ago [Hasan listed some ways to build the elementary OS SE site](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/25612) and shared some of the numbers [from Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82707/elementary-os) that outlined what was working and what needed attention. In the 822 days since his question, the answer ratio has gone up by 0.1 and the number of “avid users” has grown, but every other number has dropped dramatically.

[image: Area51 Numbers]

Given the trend, should people be asking common questions that an experienced person would know but a new user might struggle with? If memory serves, AskUbuntu did this with some of the most common questions from the Ubuntu Forums a decade back in an effort to build content for search engine results (amongst other things). By building out the Q&A site with a lot more answers, it may encourage more traffic and, more importantly, more interaction from people who have chosen elementary OS over the 100+ other distributions of Linux that are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should people be asking common questions that an experienced person would know but a new user might struggle with?

Absolutely, @matigo! That's actually one of the best ways to contribute to the site. In fact, this is [explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) across the entire Stack Exchange network.

Stack Exchange sites are prominently featured in search results due to their ability to be updated and remain relevant, so it's a great way to help people out (as opposed to other venues such as forums or chat rooms, which tend to go stale/outdated over time).

Of course, this recommendation only applies to questions that are specific to elementary OS, rather than, say, generic Ubuntu or Linux issues. But other than that, feel free to go ahead and contribute with your own question-answer pairs — it's greatly appreciated.